# Format input data using YUI 3

Tags: javascript, input, yui

Is there a way to apply a mask in a input using yui3 ?

Is it possible to have a field where the user can only enter a phone number?
And if so, how?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your best bet is to have an onChange or onKeyup (or even onValuechange - a YUI construct) handler listening on that input.  Whenever it detected a change, you would run a formatting function on the current value of the input, which formatted it in the way you wanted.

if you want to be light-handed about it, just put the dashes in where they go, for example :
`"1105551212" --> "110-555-1212"`

if you want to be heavy-handed about it, the event handler could literally strip out any non-numeric, or non-dash characters, which effectively prevents the user from entering bad input, though they could of course put in a non-existent phone number.

one step further:  do both.  strip out invalid characters, and do auto-formatting.